# Log4j creates logfile on server but doesn't write to it

Tags: log4j, glassfish-3

I'm working on a web application which is deployed on a glassfish server.
I wanted to implement the log4j framework. First, I tested everything on my local machine (local server) and it works perfect.
Now, i deployed it on a test environment and noticed two strange behaviours.

1. It creates two logfiles, one is named "server.log" and is created during the server restore function is executed. The other has the instace name, like "instance104.log" and is created while the server is starting.

But this is not the main problem. The main problem is that it doesn't write anything to any of those logfiles.

This is the logfile path from the log4j.properties:

```
log4j.appender.file1.File = /lfs/wwwmnt/appName/logs/project/${com.sun.aas.instanceName}.log
```

Does log4j need a initialization for writing logs to logfiles when it's on remote servers? Do I have to add the log4j jar to the remote sever?
Like I said, it works perfect on local evironment but on the test it just creates the logfile but doesn't write anything to it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out it was a problem with the clusterDomain domain.xml file. The configuration tags were missing (  ), and I couldn't configure them - in our business envoronment only the DevOps can do that. 
Busienss processes are a pain..